# How can I change a non-existing iCloud email address?

Tags: icloud

Setup iphone 5c for my mom 2 years ago and just performed her latest software update using her Apple ID and it worked fine.  I went to Settings > iCloud and it shows a different iCloud ID email address that has never existed.  I tried entering her Apple ID password and now it is stuck "Verifying" asking for her password to this non-existent email address.

And now she gets a message "Sign in to iCloud -- Enter the password for your Apple ID "non-existent email address".  Say what?  That is NOT her Apple ID email address!

I cannot change the email address because I cannot verify.

What can I do??

Comment: The email address doesn't have to work, it's just acting as a username.  First try using your moms most common passwords.  Second go to iforgot.apple.com and attempt to reset it (there may be challenge questions set that will let you change the password.   Short of that your going to have to get Apples help and you will need proof of ownership, because what you are dealing with is the anti-theft feature.  Resetting/clearing the phone will not help you.

Comment: I have this same issue and I was hoping there was a solution here. In my case, the old Apple ID doesn't even exist because I deleted it. Going to iforgot.apple.com doesn't work either because it recognizes that the email doesn't exist.

Comment: I'm having same issue- when I try to delete that iCloud acct on my phone- I apparently first need to turn off "Find my phone". Unfortunately- I need the password for the "no longer in use email - iCloud is showing" which of course i don't remember- thus a vicious circle. I even reopened the old email address to get a "password change" option- etc. But for some reason the Reset Email never makes its way there. I had no problem resetting new ICloud address on my iPad. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: @Robin If you have a question it should be formatted as a question and not a comment on another question.  If you have the same issue as this one, you can add a bounty to this question to get more attention to it from the community.  See [this Help topic on bounties](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for guidance.